# Why is this comparator loading down a voltage divider?

Tags: current, voltage-divider, comparator, bias

I just built up a circuit with a LM311P comparator with open collector and emitter (I don't think that's relevant). The negative input is a voltage I create with a voltage divider and the positive input is the signal I want compared.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp4l7K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However it seems like the comparator is heavily loading the voltage divider because the voltage at the negative input looks like this (yellow trace), blue trace is the output signal.

[image]

It's fluctuating by almost 2V. And this is after I already made the voltage divider smaller. The fluctuation was even worse with a combined resistance of about 20kOhms. I know I can stabilize it with a big capacitor but I first want to understand where this is coming from. Here is a screenshot from the datasheet of LM311P (http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/175000-199999/175994-da-01-en-IC_LM_311P_DIP8_TID.pdf):

[image]

The current through the voltage divider is 2.1 mA which is 7000 times as big as the worst case bias current of 300nA.

Am I missing something here? Any help understanding why this is happening would be very appreciated.

Comment: Measure your power supply - you'll probably see it is also changing. How much current do you think flows from the comparator through the transistor's BE junction with no resistance to limit it ... ?

Comment: @brhans I think that's just the way he drew it here..that transistor is internal. BEsides... if that were the case the droop would be on the output when low.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I did measure the power supply and it doesn't change (noticeably). The transistor is symbolizing the open collector output that is integrated into the comparator.

Comment: DId you leave the balance /strobe pins open?

Comment: yes I did. I just found the problem. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Comment: LOL don't leave us hanging.. what was it in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the input signal went below zero. It can go a little negative without problems but at around a diode forward drop it starts loading down the inputs.
Sorry for wasting everyone's time. Should I delete this question?

Comment: no leave it here...someone else might have the same issue.

Comment: It's a good question. Don't delete.

Comment: Go ahead and mark as accepted.